# How to compare the lengths of the elements in a column in a two-dimensional jagged array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, jagged-arrays

I was working on this part of the code (printing of the number of elements in column i) I was unsure how to check if there is any other column with a same number of elements as in column i since in my jagged array the user can not enter an array in which there are 2 or more columns with the same number of elements.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            //define / make array 
            int columns;
            int repeat;
            repeat = 0;
            //take ragged array inout
            do
            {System.out.print("How many columns : ");
            columns = input.nextInt();
            // define array
            int[][] raggedArray = new int[columns][];
            // way to enter ragged array
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
                System.out.print("Enter the number of rows for column number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
                int rows = input.nextInt();
                raggedArray[i] = new int[rows];
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter row value for row number " + (j + 1) + " : ");
                    //adding the input to array
                    raggedArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }
            // find out the number of columns
/* NEED HELP HERE to compare if there any 2 columns with the same number of elements in them / same number of rows */
            int numberOfColumns = raggedArray.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
                System.out.println("In the column " + i + " there are " + raggedArray[i].length + " rows");
                }
            } while(repeat == 99);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace these two lines:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of rows for column number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
int rows = input.nextInt();
```

With something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
    int rows;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows for column number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        rows = input.nextInt();
        int k = 0;
        for (; k < i; k++) {
            if(raggedArray[k].length == rows) break;
        }
        if(k == i) break;
        System.out.print("This number of rows has already been used.");
    }
    raggedArray[i] = new int[rows];

    // ...
}
```

The code could be simplified a little if you're familiar with, and are allowed to use, a `Set`.

```
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
    int rows;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows for column number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        rows = input.nextInt();
        if(seen.add(rows)) break;
        System.out.print("This number of rows has already been used.");
    }
    raggedArray[i] = new int[rows];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the solution (the first one without set since I am still learning java). The only question I have is why did you put int k outside of the for loop (sorry I am a novice at java programing).

Comment: You need to know the value of `k` after the loop to know whether it reached `i`, in which case this is a row value you haven't seen before. If `k` is less than `i` it's because you found a column already using this number of rows and exited using `break`. If you declared `k` within the for loop it wouldn't be visible. Makes for somewhat messy code I'm afraid.

Comment: I got a question in the line if(k == i) break;
        System.out.print("This number of rows has already been used."); why is the the break outside of the curly braces

Comment: The `if` statement, and the break, occur after the `for` loop has completed, so after the closing curly brace. It's actually breaking out of the `while` loop, because you have an unseen value for `rows`.